# How to achieve this business card look?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

you all!

I am trying to achieve this kind of look for the text in a business card but I am kind of a self-taught pseudo-designer. Can it be done on CS6?

Can you help me?

Here's the example I'm looking after and that I want to recreate.[image]

Comment: Please take this time to read [ask] and then make an [edit] to provide us with what you've tried as this seems to seek a tutorial and that isnt in scope.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking at there is a visual of some kind of emboss and/or varnish, but if you want to create the same general impression using just ink then that should be quite straightforward...

1. Create a gradient for the background that runs from about 60% black
   to about 80% black.
2. Place your required text in the centre and
   convert it to paths.
3. Create a second gradient for the text which
   goes from 100% black to about 60% black in the centre and then back
   to 100% black.
4. Play around with the tint values, angles, etc of the gradients until you like how it looks.